# Prevent to check if the checkbox is set to disabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

first I have here a line of code for checking a checkbox when you clicked on every td. I set the other checkbox into disabled. I need not to check the checkbox if it sets in disabled when I clicked on td.

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qcC5h/1/

```
<table>
    <tr><td>click me</td><td>no toggles</td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>click me</td><td>no toggles</td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled/></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
$("td").click(function(e) {
    var checkbox = $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).get(0);
    var checked = checkbox.checked;
    if (checked == false) checkbox.checked = true;
    else checkbox.checked = false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `disabled` property of checkbox.

Use

```
var checkbox = $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).get(0);
if(checkbox.disabled) //If checkbox is disable do nothing and return
    return;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sze3/)

Also

```
var checked = checkbox.checked;
if (checked == false) checkbox.checked = true;
else checkbox.checked = false;
```

above code can be simplified as

```
checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
```